# Unable to run the rails generator for Draper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, decorator, ruby-1.9.3, draper

I'm on Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.0.11. I recently installed Draper(0.12.0) gem, but I'm unable to run its generators. I get the following error when I try to run the generator on the Post model :-

```
rails generate decorator Post
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing': undefined method `config' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/draper-0.12.0/lib/draper/railtie.rb:6:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:189:in `call'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:189:in `each'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:189:in `load_generators'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/application.rb:147:in `block in load_generators'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `each'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `all'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/application.rb:147:in `load_generators'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/generators.rb:319:in `load_generators_from_railties!'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/generators.rb:278:in `lookup'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/generators.rb:141:in `find_by_namespace'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/generators.rb:161:in `invoke'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:593:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any inputs, on how can I debug this would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is this section in v0.12.0 (the one you are using) https://github.com/drapergem/draper/blob/v0.12.0/lib/draper/railtie.rb#L5-L8

When I look at the master branch they changed to code to look like: https://github.com/drapergem/draper/blob/master/lib/draper/railtie.rb#L5-L10

You should upgrade your draper gem to the latest release and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: Thank you, this worked(I used the latest gem). I'm just curious to learn one thing.. how exactly were you able to debug that out of all the files that could have thrown an error 'draper / lib / draper / railtie.rb' was the exact file where some things are going wrong . Also, you are referring to line 6 of that file right wrt error of the Rails version thats causing the above problem, right?

Comment: You can see this from the stack-trace you posted. A `method_missing` error usually means, that some code is broken and therefore can't be executed. That's way I first inspect the top-most part of the stack-trace. If you work through the stack-trace from top to bottom you'll begin with: /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48 This is a patch from rails, which is usually not the problem itself. The next line was the draper gem: "/draper/railtie.rb:6" after the colon you can see the line number.